# Problema com :nth-child() utilizando margin-right

Tags: css

Tenho uma div `.container` com várias divs `.box` onde quero mostrar 5 divs por linha quando a largura da tela for maior que `1439px`. Cada div `.box` possui uma margem `top` e `right` de `15px`, só que quero que a última div `.box` de cada linha possua a margem direita (`margin-right`) com valor `0` para que não tenha espaçamento à direita, para ficar bem ajustada dentro do `.container`.

Para isso utilizei:

```
.box{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: calc(20% - 15px);
   height: 200px;
   background: red;
   margin: 15px 15px 0 0;
}

.box:nth-child(5n+5){
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

Funciona perfeitamente, porém quando entra no `@media`, onde a resolução for menor que `1440px`, que quero mostrar, em vez de 5, 4 divs por linha:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1439px){

   .box{
      max-width: calc(25% - 15px);
   }

   .box:nth-child(4n+4){
      margin-right: 0;
   }

}
```

Veja que alterei a fórmula do `:nth-child()` para `4n+4`. Funciona, mas a 5ª div ainda continua com o `margin-right: 0` inicial definido fora do `@media`, fazendo-a ficar grudada na 6ª div:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei resetar o `margin-right` de todas as `.box` com `margin-right: 15px` antes do `.box:nth-child(4n+4)` mas mesmo assim a 5ª div continua com `margin-right: 0`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1439px){

   .box{
      max-width: calc(25% - 15px);
      margin-right: 15px; /* TENTEI RESETAR AQUI! */
   }

   .box:nth-child(4n+4){
      margin-right: 0;
   }

}
```

Creio isso se dá pela prioridade de `classe + pseudo` ser maior do que apenas `classe`.

Como fazer para que as div `.box` voltem a ter `margin-right: 15px` antes de aplicar o `.box:nth-child(4n+4){ margin-right: 0; }`?

Segue o código:

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

.container{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: calc(20% - 15px);
   height: 200px;
   background: red;
   margin: 15px 15px 0 0;
}

.box:nth-child(5n+5){
   margin-right: 0;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1439px){
   
   .box{
      max-width: calc(25% - 15px);
      margin-right: 15px;
   }

   .box:nth-child(4n+4){
      margin-right: 0;
   }
   
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="box">1</div>
   <div class="box">2</div>
   <div class="box">3</div>
   <div class="box">4</div>
   <div class="box">5</div>
   <div class="box">6</div>
   <div class="box">7</div>
   <div class="box">8</div>
   <div class="box">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vixi, Tio Sam perguntando de css, então o bagulho deve ser loko mesmo! :D

Comment: :D... deve ser moleza... eu que não tô conseguindo enxergar :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os ponto

Essa classe:

```
   .box:nth-child(4n+4){
      margin-right: 0;
   }
```

Não anula essa:

```
   .box:nth-child(5n+5){
      margin-right: 0;
   }
```

Que não anula essa

```
   .box:nth-child(odd){
      margin-right: 30px;
   }
```

São regras diferente, e uma regra não sobrescreve a outra já que elas não são iguais.

> Creio isso se dá pela prioridade de classe + pseudo ser maior do que apenas classe.

Exato, seu raciocínio está correto!

---

**Para resolver**

Vc pode incluir o nth-child(5n+5), na regra anterior tipo `.box, .box:nth-child(5n+5) { }` ai ela volta ao padrão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
  body{
      margin: 0;
   }
   
   .container{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
   }
   
   .box{
      width: 100%;
      max-width: calc(20% - 15px);
      height: 200px;
      background: red;
      margin: 15px 15px 0 0;
   }
   
   .box:nth-child(5n+5){
      margin-right: 0;
   }
   
   
@media screen and (max-width: 1439px){
  
  .box,
  .box:nth-child(5n+5) {
      max-width: calc(25% - 15px);
      margin-right: 15px;
  }

  .box:nth-child(4n+4){
      margin-right: 0;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta com o que encontrei. Abs!

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do @hugocss funciona nesse caso, mas vou deixar uma resposta que funciona de forma melhor quando tiver outras @media onde eu queira mostrar menos divs por linha, como 3 ou 2.

É só utilizar na fórmula apenas o `n`, que irá aplicar em todas as divs, pois assim terá o mesmo peso de `classe + pseudo` antes de aplicar a fórmula `xn+x`, pois o `n` é referente a todos os elementos do seletor:

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

.container{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: calc(20% - 15px);
   height: 200px;
   background: red;
   margin: 15px 15px 0 0;
}

.box:nth-child(5n+5){
   margin-right: 0;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1439px){
   
   .box{
      max-width: calc(25% - 15px);
   }

   .box:nth-child(n){
      margin-right: 15px;
   }

   .box:nth-child(4n+4){
      margin-right: 0;
   }
   
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
   
   .box{
      max-width: calc(33% - 15px);
   }

   .box:nth-child(n){
      margin-right: 15px;
   }

   .box:nth-child(3n+3){
      margin-right: 0;
   }
   
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="box">1</div>
   <div class="box">2</div>
   <div class="box">3</div>
   <div class="box">4</div>
   <div class="box">5</div>
   <div class="box">6</div>
   <div class="box">7</div>
   <div class="box">8</div>
   <div class="box">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: É interessante tb, dependendo da quantidade de regra que fizer pode economizar umas linhas de código mesmo, essas regras de nth-chilt as vezes são meio confusas mesmo